# Execute hosted service in per request scope

Tags: c#, memory-management, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, business-logic

I have a background service that runs every 30 seconds in my ASP .NET Core WebApi application. Its registered to the service container in ConfigureServices in Startup.cs by the line

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, SimpleService>();
```

Then I have this class and its upper class to execute a given method every 30 seconds:

The general background service class:

```
public abstract class BackgroundService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private Task currentTask;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource stopCts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        currentTask = ExecuteAsync(stopCts.Token);

        if (currentTask.IsCompleted)
            return currentTask;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public virtual async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (currentTask == null)
            return;

        try
        {
            stopCts.Cancel();
        }
        finally
        {
            await Task.WhenAny(currentTask, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken));
        }
    }

    protected virtual async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        DateTime nextExecution = DateTime.Now;

        do
        {
            DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

            if (nextExecution <= currentTime)
            {
                nextExecution = currentTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                await Process(cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                await Task.Delay(nextExecution - currentTime, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested);
    }

    protected abstract Task Process(CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        stopCts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

The one to use when a specific scope is needed:

```
public abstract class ScopedBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory;

    public ScopedBackgroundService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        this.serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    protected override async Task Process(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            await ProcessInScope(scope.ServiceProvider, cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    public abstract Task ProcessInScope(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

When implementing the service itself I use this class (which is also registered in the ConfigureServices method):

```
public class SimpleService : ScopedBackgroundService
{
    private ISimpleBusiness simpleBusiness;

    public SimpleService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory) : base(serviceScopeFactory)
    {
    }

    public override async Task ProcessInScope(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this.simpleBusiness = serviceProvider.GetService<ISimpleBusiness>();

        foreach (var b in simpleBusiness.GetAll())
        {
            await this.simpleBusiness.Check(b);
        }
    }
}
```

This works good. But I have the problem that after each request the used memory increased. The garbage collector also doesnt get triggered. After a while and under certain circumstances I cant detect/find the memory increases rapidly in about 20 ms by up to 150 MB.

The SimpleBusiness class (implementing the interface ISimpleBusiness) uses a db context in simpleDA obtained via constructor injection:

```
public class SimpleBusiness : ISimpleBusiness
{
    private ISimpleDA simpleDA;
    private IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment;
    ...

    public SimpleBusiness(ISimpleDA simpleDA, IHostingEnvironment environment, ...)
    {
        this.simpleDA = simpleDA;
        this.hostingEnvironment = environment;
        ...
    }
    ...
```

I guess this dbcontext and its attached objects dont get disposed/removed from memory. How can I pass the db context in a request-lifetime scope to the constructor when calling ProcessInScope in ScopedBackgroundService for the following created instances of all objects used in the underlying methods without changing the current data access and business classes/interfaces?

EDIT:

This is the memory and cpu usage over about 26 minutes.

[The usage of about 26 minutes runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiB2A.png)

Comment: Memory utilization looks flat to me. Not even any spikes. Yes, it increases drastically right at first, but that's pretty normal. Memory isn't typically released unless it's necessary, as it's better to have everything cached and sitting in RAM ready to go, as long as the system has plenty of memory. There's a number of things both in ASP.NET Core and IIS that contribute the memory load here, so it's entirely possible that there's nothing wrong at all with your service.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Although it increases about 1 MB per 2 minutes. And I can't see why. Even when calling GC.Collect() after the await Process() in the background service. And also the amount of Guid objects (which I use as identity field for entities) increase in the heap.